# Adding a ZStack around a TabView/NavigationView moves content up into safe area when .blur is used

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationview, tabview, zstack

My application uses a `TabView` and contained in it there is a `NavigationView` so I can transition to different views on the selected tabs. I am using `.navigationTitle` together with `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)` to show users where they are (in the example below the title is set to `"Pfizer"`). All is working fine as you can see below:

[image: Screenshot when TabView/NavigationView are used without a ZStack around it]

```
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            NavigationView {
                ...
```

However, as soon as I put a `ZStack` around the `TabView` (or use `.overlay`) the entire views including the navigation header move up into the safe area even though I have not specified an `.ignoresSafeArea` anywhere! Here is how it looks like when I am using `ZStack` around it:

[image: Screenshot when ZStack/TabView/NavigationView are all nested]

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                NavigationView {
                    ...
```

Note that I intend to use ZStack to conditionally show a view on top of my TabView/NavigationView as follows:

```
    @Binding var condition: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                NavigationView {
                    ...
               }
            }
            .blur(radius: condition ? 3 : 0)
            if condition {
                VStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("Some text")
                            .font(.title2).padding(.bottom)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
            }
        }
    }
```

I managed to figure out by trial and error that the problem only occurs if I am using the `.blur` view modifier on the `TabView` that is inside the `ZStack`. If I remove the `.blur` view modifier, then the problem that I described does not occur and so the initial comment of Asperi makes sense.

I do not understand this behavior and I have no idea why using `.blur` messes up the safe area. Can anybody explain this behavior to me please?

Comment: Works fine with Xcode  13.1 / iOS 15.1

Comment: I verified that I am using Xcode 13.1 / iOS 15.1, still I do have that problem as described above.

Comment: I figured out using trial and error that the problem I observed only occurs when I am using the .blur view modifier. That's the reason why Asperi was not able to reproduce the problem. Still, I do not understand it.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Why does adding .blur() mess with the safe area? I only have this problem if I apply .blur() to a TabView

Comment: Same problem still exists (blur on NavigationView). Did somebody find a workaround?

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same situation today. Did you figure out how to keep the same safearea (in my case, safearea top gets messes up when I use Zstack, TaView and .blur...